# How to fix 'Cannot read property 'document' of null' when trying to access window.opener.document

Tags: javascript, window

I'm trying to access elements in the window that opened the popup however, as the title says, I'm getting 'Cannot read property 'document' of null' when trying to access them.

I've seen a few other posts on this subject however unfortunately none of them helped in this case.

I've tried 
    `openerWindow = window.opener.document;
       selectedTableRow = openerWindow.querySelectorAll(".highlighted-rows");`

As well as
    `selectedTableRow = window.parent.document.querySelectorAll(".highlighted-rows");`

The above does run, however it brings back an empty array, even though I know that there are table rows with the class `.highlighted-rows`

And
    `selectedTableRow = window.opener.document.querySelectorAll(".highlighted-rows");`

The interesting thing is, when I try running `selectedTableRow = window.opener.document.querySelectorAll(".highlighted-rows");` through the Chrome console, it actually works and returns the row I was expecting, it's just running it through the code that fails.

Comment: The error means that `window.opener` is `null`.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks for the quick reply. I'm aware that's what the error means, sorry I should have made this more clear.
I'm wondering why I'm able to run ```window.opener.document.querySelectorAll(".highlighted-rows");``` through the Chrome console and it works though. The same line of code gives me the error if I run it through the javascript file

Comment: One does not have access cross-window like that. You'll need to use the cross-window messaging API to assist you.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Isn't that only when you don't meet the same origin policy? I don't see why I wouldn't be in-line with this policy.

Answer (score 0):

You will only have an opener if it was set.  See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener) for more details, but the important bit:

> When a window is opened from another window (using Window.open or a link with its target attribute set), it maintains a reference to that first window as window.opener. **If the current window has no opener, this method returns null**.

If you're sure the window you're trying to access should have an `opener`, can you post the code that spawned it?